# Regex pattern to extract name from emails

Tags: javascript, regex

I need some help to find a regex expression to extract user names from these emails:
(Regex newbie here)

- *john.stewartcompany1@example.com*
- *bruce.williamscompany1@example.com*
- *richard.weiss@example.com*
- *julia.palermocompany2@example.com*
- *edward.philipscompany3@example.com*

As you can see from the emails, almost all of them have the company name following the name. (company1, company2, company3)

But some emails have no company inserted. (See **richard.weiss**)
All of them will have @example.com

So I need to extract only the names, without the company, like this:

- **john.stewart**
- **bruce.williams**
- **richard.weiss**
- **julia.palermo**
- **edward.philips**

I've come up with this pattern so far:

`/(.+)(?=@example.com)/g`

This only solves half of the problem, as it keeps the company name in the names.

- john.stewart**company1**
- bruce.williams**company1**
- richard.weiss
- julia.palermo**company2**
- edward.philips**company3**

I still need to remove the **company names** from the user names.
Is there a way to accomplish this with a **single regex pattern**?

Any help appreciated.

PS:
Thanks for the replies. I forgot to mention...

The company names are **limited**.
We can safely assume from my example that there will be only
**company1**, **company2** and **company3**.

Thanks.

Comment: Unless you know the company names in advance, it's not possible, as there is no way to tell whether (for example) `john.waterford` is `John Water` of `Ford` or just `John Waterford`

Comment: Would the company names always be `company1` etc.?  Do you know all the expected company names?

Comment: And if you don’t know the company names, you need to know the full list of possible last names. Otherwise there is now way of separating last name from company name.

Comment: There will be only company1, company2 and company3. They are limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^.*?(?=(?:company1|company2|company3)?@)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2xCGTo/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?=(?:company1|company2|company3)?@)` - a positive lookahead that requires the following subpatterns to match immediately to the right of the current location:

  - `(?:company1|company2|company3)?` - an optional `company1`, `company2` or `company3` char sequence
  - `@` - a `@` char.